# Did Peter Graves also narrate defense-related videos for the US government in the '50s and '60s?

Tags: voice-acting, acting-career

A link to the Ars Technica article [Best bad idea ever? Why Putin’s nuclear-powered missile is possible… and awful](https://arstechnica.com/science/2018/03/best-bad-idea-ever-why-putins-nuclear-powered-missile-is-possible-and-awful/) was included as a comment below my question [How did Northrop Grumman propose to make the Global Hawk nuclear powered?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49890/14213).

That article links to the video [Nuclear Ramjet (Project Pluto) to Drive "Big Stick" SLAM Missile circa 1959 USAF-Convair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_SCuPId8KA).

The narrator sounds to me to possibly be the actor [Peter Graves](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0336335/), and there are comments about this on the video's page as well.

Did Graves work extensively as a narrator for the US government in defense related films in the 1950s and 1960s?

**edit:** This [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/428341/83380) links to the video [Gyroscopic Instruments - U.S. Navy Aviation Training Film (1960)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnKloSdUJLo) which of course does not have credits either, but that certainly sounds like Peter Graves to me.